# How to prepare modules.dep and ld.so.cache while cross-compiling?

Tags: embedded-linux, powerpc

I'm cross-compiling kernel modules and some libraries on x86 for ppc.
Is it possible to create ld.so.cache and modules.dep on my host system?

P.S I'm using ELDK tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modules.dep should be generated when the modules are built.  It's also a text file so is readable on either architecture.

I'm pretty sure it'd be hard to generate ld.so.cache on anything but the system target system.  It's a binary file that built up given the specific libraries available on your rootfs and configuration in /etc/ld.so.conf.

Answer (score 0):

`depmod` can run just fine against foreign architecture modules.  Assuming you've built your kernel and deployed your modules (eg 3rd party modules) to your system-root:

```
/sbin/depmod -ae -F /path/to/System.map -b /path/to/system/root <kernel-version-name>
```

Haven't found a solution for `ldconfig`, yet.